# Sequence of Four Words

Tags: riddle, word, pattern, rhyme

With A, it's a fellow whose work is for hire.
With E, it's a place where there might be a fire.
With I, it's a fellow who hasn't much class.
With O, something pleasant to find in your glass.

Surmise, then, the pattern that I have designed,
And tell me the four words that I have in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's...

> `h_ck`

With A, it's a fellow whose work is for hire.

> A **hack** is another word for a taxi, like the kind you hire. Thanks alexmc. It is also a word for "One who undertakes unpleasant or distasteful tasks for money or reward; a hireling", so thanks Pete.

With E, it's a place where there might be a fire.

> **Heck**, like fire and brimstone et al

With I, it's a fellow who hasn't much class.

> **Hick**, a country hick or hillbilly

With O, something pleasant to find in your glass.

> **Hock**, a type of wine.

Comment: A hack's another word for a taxi, could be a reference to that?

Comment: @alexmc I had no clue. Updated!

Comment: Kindly clear my confusion, but I don't think heck is directly defined as fire and brimstone. I feel that heck is an alternate for hell, which is a place of fire.

Comment: @CodeNewbie oh, my bad. I've always assumed fire and brimstone [referred to hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_brimstone).

Comment: According to Oxford American Dictionary "fire and brimstone" is "the torments of hell".

Comment: Hack can mean "One who undertakes unpleasant or distasteful tasks for money or reward; a hireling." according to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hack), which fits in better with the clue

Comment: @Pete good point! You and alexmc are good.

Comment: Al.Sal, can you update your answer as Pete and CodeNewbie have suggested?

Comment: @dennisdeems just did it!